# Equivalent to DirectInput for Windows Store Apps?

Tags: windows-10, directx-11

I am building a game for Windows 10 that utilizes input to draw on the screen, but the fidelity is lacking. It is not accurate enough to draw a straight line if you draw fast. That's when I thought of DirectInput, which I've used in C++ games for Windows 7, but that API is not available for Store Apps... is there an equivalent, which will increase my accuracy for the drawing?

Answer (score 1):

DirectInput is not supported for Windows 8 Store or UWP. Use of DirectInput for mouse and keyboard has been discouraged for many years.

For touch & mouse, you use the unified pointer interfaces. You can also use relative mouse data which might be more what you are looking for in terms of resolution.

See [Responding to touch input (DirectX and C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh994931.aspx) and [Developing mouse controls (DirectX and C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh994925.aspx).

Keep in mind that UWP uses DIPS so you have to convert to raw pixels using the current DPI setting.